# Can a single page can be used for multiple skbs which are not fragments

Tags: networking, network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a networking hardware which does Rx coalescing , in which frames partaining to a nic device are combined and send as a big chunk ( Greater than mtu) to the driver.

In the driver i have to split them according to mtu size and need to sent up to the stack.

1. I want to know is there a way to allocate a page so that i can split that after the device DMA's the frame ?
2. Can a single Page can be shared across multiple skbs (not accross frags in a same skb)? If so what special care i need to take which unmapping the page?
3. Is there a mechanism to allocate sgs and map them to a page and after the
   device does DMA , split this sgs and point to skb and send to the stack

Waiting for the reponses

Thanks
pradeep G

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly, the NIC is keeping all of the packet overhead (Ethernet header, etc) for multiple packets, but giving them to the driver as one large frame? And then the driver is expected to split the frame back up into individual packets?

Comment: mmm actually the NIC is combing multiple packets in one big frame ( greate than nic mtu) and the driver is expected to split according to mtu size as individual packets and send to stack

Comment: Large Receive Offload ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload